# sql query to find what is not in group three

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have one `SQL Table` in which some dummy data. 
i want that dummy data and update that row with `column type`

```
my table tbl

ID  D1  M1  C1  QTY TYPE

1   D1  M1  C1  1   Y
2   D1  M2  C1  2   Y
3   D1  M3  C1  3   Y
4   D1  M1  C1  1   Y

5   D2  M1  C1  1   Y
6   D2  M2  C1  2   Y
7   D2  M3  C2  3   Y
8   D2  M1  C1  1   Y
9   D2  M2  C1  2   Y

10  D3  M1  C1  1   Y
11  D3  M2  C1  2   Y
12  D3  M3  C1  3   Y
13  D3  M1  C1  1   Y
14  D3  M2  C1  2   Y
15  D3  M3  C1  3   Y
16  D3  M1  C2  1   Y
```

grouping on Column `D1` and `M1`

I have a N no. of records, now I have to identify group of 3 record and if any record remain then it should be set as "No" else "yes"
Ex:

condition 1: If I have 4 records, then make a group of 3-3 records so remain last 1 record should be set an "no".

condition 2: If I have 5 records, then make a group of 3-3 records so remain last 2 records will be set as "No"

Condition 3: if I have 7 records, then make a group of 3-3 records so remain last 1 record will be set as "No"

my expected answer is as below

```
 ID D1  M1  C1  QTY TYPE

1   D1  M1  C1  1   YES
2   D1  M2  C1  2   YES
3   D1  M3  C1  3   YES
4   D1  M1  C1  1   NO

5   D2  M1  C1  1   YES
6   D2  M2  C1  2   YES
7   D2  M3  C2  3   YES
8   D2  M1  C1  1   NO
9   D2  M2  C1  2   NO

10  D3  M1  C1  1   YES
11  D3  M2  C1  2   YES
12  D3  M3  C1  3   YES
13  D3  M1  C1  1   YES
14  D3  M2  C1  2   YES
15  D3  M3  C1  3   YES
16  D3  M1  C2  1   NO
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41bd7/1)

Please tell me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by d1 order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by d1) as cnt
      from tbl t
     )
update toupdate
    set type = (case when seqnum  <= 3*(cnt /3) then 'yes' else 'no' end);
```

You can also run similar logic as a `select`:

```
select t.*, (case when seqnum  <= 3*(cnt /3) then 'yes' else 'no' end)
from (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by d1 order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by d1) as cnt
      from tbl t
     ) t;
```